# how to align input text to right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a google advanced search. I'm having trouble with the input text, I want to align them right just like Google, at a close distance and all accordingly.
This is my html:

```
     <form action="https://www.google.com/advanced">
            <div id="advanced">
            Find pages with...<br/><br/>
            all these words:<input type="text" name="words"><br/><br/>
            this exact word or phrase:<input type="text" name="exact"><br/><br/>
            any of these words:<input type="text" name="any"><br/></br>
            none of these words:<input type="text" name="none"><br/><br/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Advanced Search">
     </form>
```

This is my css:

```
#advanced input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 15px; 
    padding: 5px 10px;   
    background-image: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

But that makes them go to the right... Way too much. I wish I could adjust it. This is how it looks like.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX83k.png

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can add a margin-right, i.e., margin-right: 40%, to pull the input fields to the left by some amount.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this worked

Comment: Okay I'm really sorry haha... But at first glance it does look like it worked, but it's actually not in line with the text, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ1JH.png

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply a `width` or `max-width` to the container (`#advanced`) in your current code:

```css
#advanced {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 520px;
}

#advanced input[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/advanced">
  <div id="advanced">
    Find pages with...<br/><br/> all these words:<input type="text" name="words"><br/><br/> this exact word or phrase:<input type="text" name="exact"><br/><br/> any of these words:<input type="text" name="any"><br/></br>
    none of these words:<input type="text" name="none"><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Advanced Search">
</form>
```

Comment: @Angely you can up-vote it if it was a good one and you can mark it as solved if it solved your issue as well.

Answer (score -1):

use flexbox

```css
#advanced {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and remove

display: block;
float: right;

and remove the BR's

Comment: This is what it looks like if I do that

Comment: If you see this again it's okay now, I fixed it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it is flex-direction: column; and try remove the width

Comment: Nope it didn't work, and I was wrong... The past thing didn't work either